# Why after i key in curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_18.x | sudo -E bash - in my WSL terminal, nothing happens?

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

[PPA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJCLv.png)

After i key in curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_18.x | sudo -E bash - in my WSL terminal, however nothing happens. No installation done.

I did try using sudo apt update. But I cannot connect to ubuntu server. Thus, I am trying use PPA method.

How should I do , so I can install node.js in my WSL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not try and use `apt` to install node, it is outdated and you will run into problems.
The only clean trouble free install when setting up wsl that I use is:

1. curl:  `sudo apt-get install curl`
2. NVM:   `curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/master/install.sh | bash`
3. Check that NVM was installed: `command -v nvm`
4. *Then* you can install node with: `nvm install --lts`
5. Check install: node --version

Use NVM (Node Version Manager) to install and use any other node versions you wish.
Example: `NVM use 16` NVM will start node version 16.

When you install NVM, it will list all of the commands you can use.